# How can I start a systemd service when a given USB device (ethernet dongle) is plugged in?

Tags: usb, ethernet, arch-linux, systemd

I have an USB ethernet dongle I use for ethernet access, but I'd like to automatically start `netctl-ifplugd@...` when plugging it in. (Not to be confused with plugging in the *ethernet cable* - that's handled by `netctl-ifplugd`.) How can I make this happen?

I've seen [How to write a systemd service that depends on a device being present?](https://superuser.com/questions/851846/how-to-write-a-systemd-service-that-depends-on-a-device-being-present) but that doesn't seem to be about plugging it in, just about it being present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've seen "How to write a systemd service that depends on a device being present?" but that doesn't seem to be about plugging it in, just about it being present.

It's very similar, only you need the opposite dependency: instead of (or perhaps in addition to) your service depending on the device, **you want the virtual *device* unit to depend on your service.**

In fact, despite the linked question's *title* seemingly asking the opposite thing, the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/851966) in the thread already documents one of the exact methods that would make the device start a service (the udev-rule method).

But if you have an *exact* .device unit name, it's simpler to use systemd dependencies directly:

#### If the exact sysfs path is known:

For example, you have determined that the device is *sys-subsystem-net-devices-usb0.device*. You can use various ways of expanding that unit (despite it being virtual), such as `foo.device.d/*.conf` drop-ins or `foo.device.wants/` symlinks (which work the same way as e.g. *multi-user.target.wants/*).

- You can add an `[Install]` configuration in your service, then *systemctl enable* it:

  ```
  [Install]
  WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
  ```
- Or you can get the same result directly with `systemctl add-wants`:

  ```
  # systemctl add-wants sys-subsystem-net-devices-usb0.device netctl-ifplugd@usb0.service
  ```
- Both methods just result in a symlink that can be made by hand via `ln -s`.

This generally works the same for user units.

#### If only partial name (or some combination of other properties) is known:

Write a udev rule that matches your device (the exact udev rule syntax is out of scope here) and have it set the `SYSTEMD_WANTS` udev property (aka "device environment variable") indicating your unit:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="usb*", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="netctl-ifplugd@%k.service"
```

As all `*.rules` files are processed in alphabetical order, make sure your rule is placed later than systemd's own "persistent network interfaces" rules.

This works with user units if you use `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}`.

---

You might be tempted to use `RUN+="/bin/systemctl start foo"` via udev. Don't do that. But if you do, then at least use the `systemctl --no-block` option so that you won't create a possible deadlock between the two components.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this same problem using the add-wants systemd command - I just got a new ethernet adapter ens4u1u2 so I enabled `netctl-ifplugd@ens4u1u2.service` and then tried to add-wants using `sudo systemctl add-wants sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens4u1u2.device netctl-ifplugd@ens4u1u2.service`, but I get `Failed to add dependency: Unit file sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens4u1u2.device does not exist.`. Running `systemctl status sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens4u1u2.device` shows that the device is active but it won't accept it for add-wants. Enabling the .device gives the same error.

Comment: If systemd no longer allows this in add-wants, then just create the symlink manually at `/etc/systemd/system/sys-....device.wants/`, or use the udev rule method (which might be preferred).

Comment: Thanks, I got the udev method to work. For posterity, what I ended up with is `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="usb*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8153", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="netctl-ifplugd@ens4u1u2.service"`, using values from `lsusb`

Answer (score 1):

[udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev) is what you want to look at.  It will allow you to do things like execute commands when hardware is plugged in, unplugged, state changes happen etc.  You can also specify a wide variety of criteria to control triggering (i.e. when any storage device is plugged in or just a particular model from a particular manufacturer etc.)  You should see any existing rules on your system in /etc/udev/rules.d/