# Make systemd service wait for a device, generically

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, systemd

Currently, I am using the following config to make sure that my display manager waits to start until after the DRM driver is loaded (otherwise X.org cannot start):

udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card0", TAG+="systemd"
```

systemd service override:

```
[Unit]
Requires=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:01:00.0-drm-card0.device
After=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:01:00.0-drm-card0.device
```

This gets the job done, but it seems fragile.

Is it possible to shorten the `Requires=` and `After=` lines to refer to the DRM device generically, without using the full PCI path?

I am using Ubuntu 19.04.

**Edit to satisfy the duplicate police:**

The suggested duplicate asks about automatically starting a systemd service when a device is plugged in.  This question is about waiting to start a service **which is already started automatically** until a given device is initialized.  Two different questions.  Read them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I start a systemd service when a given USB device (ethernet dongle) is plugged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/1364509/how-can-i-start-a-systemd-service-when-a-given-usb-device-ethernet-dongle-is-p)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if the tagged device has an associated node in /dev, you can use that directly:

```
Requires=dev-dri-card0.device
After=dev-dri-card0.device
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  And now I see that the "-a" flag to "systemctl list-units -a -t device" would have shown me this device as well.

Comment: How would I wait for `/dev/input/event5`. There does not seem to be a unit for that.

Comment: @RichardNeumann: You need to have udev tag the devices accordingly for systemd to monitor them (similar to how it's done in OP's question, except the ACTION filter needs updating). A catch-all rule for /dev/input would be `ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="input", TAG+="systemd"`, similar to the ones in `99-systemd.rules`.